# What's the difference between "knowledge" and "full knowledge" when it comes to sin?

Tags: catholicism, mortal-sin

This is actually not a speculative question! :) An act committed with mere knowledge is not a mortal sin--it must be full knowledge. So, what is the difference between mere knowledge and the full knowledge required for a mortal sin? Where's the cutoff?

I don't know if this needs to be a second question--what's the difference between mere consent, which does not result in a mortal sin, and complete consent, which does? What's the cutoff?

The Catechism gives a partial answer: 1862 One commits venial sin when. . .he disobeys the moral law in a grave matter, but without full knowledge or without complete consent.

But it doesn't give a cutoff point for knowledge or consent. What's the cutoff? When does knowledge become the "full knowledge" and consent "complete consent" required for mortal sin? And how could I be absolutely sure I crossed that line?

Comment: Please answer in light of Amoris Laetitia 301-306: Hence it is can no longer
simply be said that all those in any “irregular”
situation are living in a state of mortal sin and are
deprived of sanctifying grace. More is involved
here than mere ignorance of the rule. A subject
may know full well the rule, yet have great difficulty in understanding “its inherent values”,or be in a concrete situation which does not allow
him or her to act differently and decide otherwise without further sin. As the Synod Fathers
put it, “factors may exist which limit the ability to
make a decision”

Comment: It takes more than mere knowledge and mere consent to commit a mortal sin--I can know something is wrong, and I can consent to doing it, and that's sin, but not a mortal sin. I have to have "full" knowledge and "complete" consent to commit a mortal sin. So, my question is--where's the cutoff? When do I move from having knowledge to having "full knowledge?" When do I move from having consent to "complete" consent?

Comment: related: cf. the last quotation of § "Moral certititude" of [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89041/1787)

Comment: How does moral certainty relate to full knowledge? They are both Catholic terms, but are they about the same subject?

Comment: Moral certitude regards judgments (in your case: judging whether a sin is mortal or venial).

Comment: It involves legal judgments--I can judge with moral certitude that an act is against the law. It doesn't involve judging the morality of the act. "In Roman Catholic canon law, moral certitude describes the ecclesiastical judge’s full conviction that a defendant is guilty or that a statement of claim made by a civil plaintiff is rightful."

Comment: Amoris Laetitia is a red herring. It doesn't really affect what is full knowledge for mortal sin for the exact reason that the situation of "irregular" was never about stating that someone was in mortal sin per se.

Comment: @Ashpenaz St. Augustine (_Contra Faust._ xxii): "Sin is a word, deed, or desire against the eternal law." (cf. [I-II q. 71 a. 6](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS071.html#FSQ71A6THEP1)).

Answer (score 2):

St Thomas says, in the [Prima Secundae, QQ. 76 a. 4](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/2076.htm#article4)

> Since every sin is voluntary, ignorance can diminish sin, in so far as it diminishes its voluntariness; and if it does not render it less voluntary, it nowise alleviates the sin.

In other words, if knowing more about a sin would not have stopped you from committing X mortal sin, the ignorance you did have does not diminish the guilt of that sin.

Moreover, "ignorance which is not the cause of the sin being committed, but is concomitant with it, neither diminishes nor increases the sin."

> Therefore sin cannot be alleviated by any ignorance, but only by such as is a cause of the sin being committed, and yet does not excuse from the sin altogether.

Ignorance "which is a cause" is the kind of ignorance I noted above. Ignorance can be a cause of sin insofar as it is a lack of knowledge that would prevent one from committing the sin. This depends on the person and circumstances, as he notes in Article 1:

> **If a man's will be so disposed** that he would not be restrained from the act of patricide, even though he recognized his father, his ignorance about his father is not the cause of his committing the sin, but is concomitant with the sin: wherefore such a man sins, not "through ignorance" but "in ignorance," as the Philosopher states (Ethic. iii, 1).

"Now," he says, "it happens sometimes that such like ignorance is directly and essentially **voluntary**, as when a man is purposely ignorant that he may sin more freely," which makes the sin **more** voluntary and more sinful. Other kinds of ignorance may be *indirect* such as being unwilling to study as hard as one should, resulting in ignorance which causes some sin.

**In sum, the question that must be asked is "would this knowledge have prevented the person from sinning?"** The cutoff is whether the person would have still committed that sin with the knowledge he was missing.

This is basically just restated by the Catechism and by AL 301-302, with some possible examples. Part of why there just isn't a single hard-and-fast set of rules that apply always to everyone is because it requires reflection and discernment, sometimes especially by a confessor. Hence questions like these can easily veer into pastoral territory, because they are pastoral by nature when it comes to individuals!

"And how could I be absolutely sure I crossed that line?" By forming your conscience well and simply asking your confessor if in doubt about anything. Just about every online resource dealing with this ends in "when in doubt, ask your confessor!" for the reason I just stated.

---

[Why is complete consent listed as a requirement for an act to be a mortal sin?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/77859/why-is-complete-consent-listed-as-a-requirement-for-an-act-to-be-a-mortal-sin) was answered and that seems to answer your question on consent. If not you may want to ask a separate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136225/discussion-between-supportivedante-and-ashpenaz).